# Error in installing react app and can't find the path of my folder

Tags: node.js, reactjs, command

while installing create-react-app get these error

npm ERR! Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...0","mocha":"^5.2.0","'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\aya hosny\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-10-06T05_50_02_849Z-debug.log

and can't find the path of the folder

thanks in advance for helping

http://prntscr.com/pfge6a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try run this if you're using npm.

`npm cache clean --force`

or yarn

`yarn cache clean`